# Subtab open using workspace API

Tags: lightning, workspaceapi

In one of my scenarios, we need to open a flexipage as a new subtab on click on some text link.

Let's take there are list of records like 
0001 , 0002, 0003

On click on 0001 we need to open a new flexipage as a subtab and need to pass 0001 in URL.

We are able to open new subtab with the following code

```
Let workspaceApi = component.find('workspace'); 
WorkspaceAPi.opensubTab(
    ParentabId : response
    url : 'lightning/n/'+myflexipagename+'?info='+0001}),
    Focus : true 
})
```

Now I'm back to my parent tab and click on 0002. 
Now also I need to open one more new subtab.
This is not working.

Comment: Please take the time to [edit] your question properly. The code, as written, would not work because of case-sensitivity problems all over. It needs to be written as correctly as possible, and ideally as a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) so we can help identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, the issue is not related to subtabs *per se*. Your issue is that you need to know which item has been clicked in a list, and use that information to dynamically determine the URL you wish to open.

One common pattern for doing so is using `data-` attributes on your list elements, which you can then acquire in your controller. As a rough sketch, it can look like this:

```
<aura:iteration items="{! v.myObjects }" var="obj">
    <li>
        <a onclick="{! c.openSubtab }" data-target="{! obj.Id }"> {! obj.Name } </a>
    </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

Then, in the controller,

```
openSubtab : function(component, event, helper) {
    let targetId = event.currentTarget.dataset.target;

    let workspaceApi = component.find('workspace'); 
    workspaceApi.openSubtab(
        // generate parameters based on `targetId`
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is late answer but developer tends to use `url` everytime, where as salesforce has introduced other params for these specific scenario.

This is a scenario where you cannot use a `url` based parameter as the flexipage name would be same. I suggest you to use [Page Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_open_pagereference.htm) based parameter and pass your unique id in `state`, so that it open new flexipage with different param each time you click.